# How to run a bat file from a C# program?

Tags: c#, function, batch-file

so i need a simple function to run bat file.
How to do such thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

In the simplest form, you can call it like this

```
Process.Start("thebatchfile.bat")
```

Answer (score 12):

[`Process.Start("file.bat");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You may find you need to include the directory in the call;

using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start(@"C:....\thebatfile.bat");

If for example the file takes arguments in (not for Bat file granted), they too can be added in the "Start()"method. Seperate Start("....thebatfile", "-s - t 3600"); with a comma. Intellisense is great for looking at the overload options of the method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this is any different, but in a project I inherited, we used
`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell`.

`Shell("file.bat", AppWinStyle.NormalFocus, True, -1)`
The last two parameters specify if the calling program should wait for the command to finish, and how long it should wait for it to time out (-1 for forever)